# winapi - display int variable value in MessageBox using macros

Tags: c, winapi, macros

For debugging purposes I am trying to make a short macros to display various types, instead of constant copying all the `MessageBox` functions' params.

For strings I have following macros:

```
#define DEBUG(x) MessageBox(NULL, x,"DEBUG",MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
```

Calling it working great, whether I pass variable (array of `char`) or direct string.

Now, I try to make the same thing for `int`. Have defined macros like this:

```
#define STRIGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRIGIFY(x)
#define DEBUGINT(x) DEBUG(TOSTRING(x))
```

It works only in case I pass direct integer value:

```
DEBUGINT(742);
```

However if I pass `int` variable, `MessageBox` displays variable name instead of its value:

```
int count = 3;
DEBUGINT(count);
```

The thing I find pretty interesting for me is that I can pass literally anything in `DEBUGINT` macros and it will still work:

```
DEBUGINT(some unescaped string)
```

How do I define a macros that would use a variable value instead of its name?

Comment: Don't do this. Macros are not the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The preprocessor doesn't know anything about variables or their values, because it doesn't do anything run-time only at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question as it was asked, but I'll risk my reputation and suggest a different solution.

PLEASE, do yourself a favor and never use `MessageBox()` or other modal UI to display debug information. If you do want to interrupt program execution at that point, use the breakpoint; it also allows you to attach the condition, so that you don't need to examine the value manually.

If you do not want the interruption, just print the value to a debug output window using `::OutputDebugString()`. That can be seen in the debugger if it is attached, or via `DebugView` tool.

Another small suggestion (for Visual Studio users): if you prepend your output with a source file name and the code line number, double-clicking on that line in the output window will take you straight to that line. Just use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in your formatted string.

Comment: Little known, there is a logging/tracing framework built into Windows: [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx). This is helpful if you want to keep logging/tracing code in a released product. You can enable and disable logging/tracing dynamically at runtime by attaching a listener.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable argument list

```
#include <stdio.h>
void message(const char* format, ...)
{
    int len;
    char *buf;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    len = _vscprintf(format, args) + 1;  //add room for terminating '\0'
    buf = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    vsprintf_s(buf, len, format, args);

    MessageBoxA(0,buf,"debug",0);
    //OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    free(buf);
}

message("test %s %d %d %d", "str", 1, 2, 3);
```

You might also want to change to unicode version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "print" the variable to a buffer (array of `char`) using something like `sprintf` (or `snprintf` in VS 2015) and pass the resulting output to `MessageBox` as the string to be displayed.

Comment: Any way to wrap this conversion in macros?

Comment: Something like this: `#define DEBUGINT(x) { char buf[16]; int value = x; sprintf(buf, "%d", value); DEBUG(buf) }`